# R: chisq.test at 99%

Tags: r, chi-squared

Is there a way to set chi sq test confidence from 95% to 99%?

The base function

> `chisq.test()`

don't complains this function...

Edit:

I don't ask for p-values. My question is about confidence risk .

The alpha risk (confidence) of chisq test is by default 0.05. I would like to set it to 0.01 (99% confidence).
The alpha risk is the cutoff for the statistic X. For a given Chi distribution whit 'x' degrees of freedom, the alpha risk correspond to a "X risk statistic". If 'X statistic of our data' is greater than 'X risk statistic' we rejects H0. The we can calculate p-values, that can be interpreted as the probability that our H1 is true.

I would change the confidence risk, from 0.05 to 0.01. If we change the confidence risk, the p-values changes. for example a p-value of 0.001 for 95% confidence, could be 0.2 for 99% confidence.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `chisq.test` returns a p-value.

Comment: I don't ask for p-values. My question is about confidence risk .

The alpha risk (confidence) of chisq test is by default 0.05. I would like to set it to 0.01 (99% confidence).
The alpha risk is the cutoff for the statistic X. For a given Chi distribution whit 'x' degrees of freedom, the alpha risk correspond to a "X risk statistic". If 'X statistic of our data' is greater than 'X risk statistic' we rejects H0. The we can calculate p-values

I would change the confidence risk (CR). If we change CR, the p-values changes. i.e. a p-value of 0.001 for 95% CR, could be 0.2 for 99% CR.

Comment: You're first of all mixing up a lot of terms. The alpha "risk" you talk about is the alpha-error, and that is something you choose. If you say it's 0.01, then it's 0.01. Doesn't change the output in chisq.test one bit. Second, there's something called a confidence interval, but that doesn't have anything to do with the Chi-2 distribution to which the test statistic is compared. Third, your p-value only changes when you change the distribution from which you derive it. If you change your p-value any other way, you didn't understand the meaning of a p-value...

Comment: Please don't crosspost: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79900/r-change-confidence-risk-of-chisq

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the returned `p.value` with your criterion:

```
chisq.test(x)$p.value < (1 - 0.99)
```

This will return a logical value.

Comment: I don't ask for p-values. My question is about confidence risk . The alpha risk (confidence) of chisq test is by default 0.05. I would like to set it to 0.01 (99% confidence). The alpha risk is the cutoff for the statistic X. For a given Chi distribution whit 'x' degrees of freedom, the alpha risk correspond to a "X risk statistic". If 'X statistic of our data' is greater than 'X risk statistic' we rejects H0. The we can calculate p-values I would change the confidence risk (CR). If we change CR, the p-values changes. i.e. a p-value of 0.001 for 95% CR, could be 0.2 for 99% CR.